# RISC-V Implement a discrete function without branching

Tags: arrays, function, indexing, riscv, branchless

Consider the discrete-valued function f defined on integers in the set {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}. Definition:

```
f(-3) = 6
f(-2) = 61
f(-1) = 17
f(0) = -38
f(1) = 19
f(2) = 42
f(3) = 5
```

I am trying to implement a function "f" in RISC V that does not use branchings nor jumps to evaluate the function. a0 will be the value to evaluate in f, [ essentially: f(a0) ], while a1 will point to the address of the output array (see code below).

My code so far:

```
.globl f

.data
neg3:   .asciiz "f(-3) should be 6, and it is: "
neg2:   .asciiz "f(-2) should be 61, and it is: "
neg1:   .asciiz "f(-1) should be 17, and it is: "
zero:   .asciiz "f(0) should be -38, and it is: "
pos1:   .asciiz "f(1) should be 19, and it is: "
pos2:   .asciiz "f(2) should be 42, and it is: "
pos3:   .asciiz "f(3) should be 5, and it is: "

output: .word   6, 61, 17, -38, 19, 42, 5
.text
main:
    la a0, neg3
    jal print_str
    li a0, -3
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(-3); should be 6
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    la a0, neg2
    jal print_str
    li a0, -2
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(-2); should be 61
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    la a0, neg1
    jal print_str
    li a0, -1
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(-1); should be 17
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    la a0, zero
    jal print_str
    li a0, 0
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(0); should be -38
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    la a0, pos1
    jal print_str
    li a0, 1
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(1); should be 19
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    la a0, pos2
    jal print_str
    li a0, 2
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(2); should be 42
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    la a0, pos3
    jal print_str
    li a0, 3
    la a1, output
    jal f               # evaluate f(3); should be 5
    jal print_int
    jal print_newline

    li a0, 10
    ecall

# f takes in two arguments:
# a0 is the value we want to evaluate f at
# a1 is the address of the "output" array (defined above).
# 
f:
    
    #store the value of a0 in temp register
    add t0, a0, x0
    
    #store numerical value to get correct output index
    addi t1, x0, 3
    
    #add the numerical value 3 to the argument value 
    #to get the correct output array index value
    add t2, t1, t0
    
    #store size of int
    addi t3, x0, 4
    
    #index the output array
    mul t4, t2, t3
    add t4, t4, t2
    
    lw ra, 0(t4)
    

    jr ra            

print_int:
    mv a1, a0
    li a0, 1
    ecall
    jr    ra

print_str:
    mv a1, a0
    li a0, 4
    ecall
    jr    ra

print_newline:
    li a1, '\n'
    li a0, 11
    ecall
    jr    ra
```

It is clear that adding the value of 3 to the passed in argument a0 will index correctly to the output array. I am unsure if I did this correctly in my code and would like some advice.

Comment: Did you try running it?  Did it crash?  What line caused it to crash?  Who produced the value that caused that line to crash?

Comment: If you want to troll your professor, you should compute the lagrange polynomial that interpolates these points, and implement that polynomial as a long and tedious sequence of additions, multiplications and integer divisions of the input value.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot two bugs in your implementation of `f`:

1. `add t4, t4, t2`: Here you are adding the address offset in the array `t4 = (a0 + 3) * 4` to the index in the array (`t2 = a0 + 3`), when instead you want to add the offset and the array pointer (`a1`):
   `add t4, t4, a1`.
2. `lw ra, 0(t4)`: Here you are loading the value from the array into the **r**eturn **a**ddress register `ra`, which holds the address of the instruction to jump back (return) to in the calling function, and is used by `jr ra`.
   Instead you want to load the value into `a0`, which is the canonical return value register:
   `lw a0, 0(t4)`.

---

There are some possible improvements:

```
    #store the value of a0 in temp register
    add t0, a0, x0

    #store numerical value to get correct output index
    addi t1, x0, 3
    
    #add the numerical value 3 to the argument value 
    #to get the correct output array index value
    add t2, t1, t0
```

1. There is no reason to copy `a0` to `t0`, just use `a0` directly in the last instruction.
2. There's also no reason to load the immediate value `3` into `t1`, just turn the last instruction into an `addi`.

Combined, the replacement for the above three instructions is this one instruction:

```
    # add 3 to argument value
    addi t2, a0, 3
```

---

There is more:

```
    #store size of int
    addi t3, x0, 4
    
    #index the output array
    mul t4, t2, t3
    add t4, t4, a1     # t2 replaced by a1, see above
```

You may have noticed that there is no `muli` instruction, so the immediate value `4` must be loaded into register `t3` before multiplying.
Furthermore, `mul` is part of the M-extension (not supported by all processors), and multiplication is generally a complicated, slow operation.

Therefore I propose to replace multiplication by 4 with a left shift by 2, which exploits the binary representation of integers and produces the same result - at least for unsigned values.
The computed index should always be `>= 0`, so this is safe.

There is a left shift immediate instruction `slli`, which is part of all base RISC-V ISAs, and shifting is usually faster than multiplication.
The three instructions above can be replaced by just two:

```
    # index the output array
    # (multiply by 4 / left shift by 2, then add array address)
    slli t4, t2, 2
    add  t4, t4, a1     # t2 replaced by a1, see above
```

---

Now combining all bug fixes and improvements, the whole function takes just five instructions instead of eight:

```
# a0: argument value ; a1: array address
f:
    # add 3 to argument value
    addi t2, a0, 3

    # index the output array
    # (multiply by 4 / left shift by 2, then add array address)
    slli t4, t2, 2
    add  t4, t4, a1     # t2 replaced by a1, see above

    # load value from output array
    lw a0, 0(t4)        # ra replaced by a0, see above

    # return to calling function
    jr ra
```

---

Now, let's take a final look at what a modern compiler like clang 11 with optimizations can produce ([godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/Eb3YsK6Wd)) when we give it the same function implemented in C:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t f(int32_t a0, int32_t a1[]) {
    return a1[a0 + 3];
}
```

Here's the result with some comments I added:

```
f:
    # multiply argument value by 4
    slli a0, a0, 2

    # add array address
    add  a0, a0, a1

    # load array value at three places (= 12 bytes) further
    lw   a0, 12(a0)

    # return to calling function
    ret
```

This is only four instructions, let's discuss this:

1. `ret` is just a short-hand notation for `jr ra`, same as what we have.
2. Register `a0` is reused by all instructions. This is perfectly legal.
   A benefit of using `a0` is that this register can be used by the compressed instructions of the C-extension. The `tN` registers cannot.
3. The compiler used the same trick I proposed to replace `addi` and `mul` with `slli`.
4. The initial `addi t2, a0, 3` is missing.
   Instead, the compiler internally multiplied the constants `3` and `4` and used the resulting value `12` as the immediate value in `lw a0, 12(a0)`.
   The original address calculation was `(a0 + 3) * 4 + a1`. The compiler transformed this into `a0 * 4 + a1 + 12`, which is equivalent. Then it moves the addition of `12` into the address generation step of the `lw` instruction, thereby saving the `addi` instruction.